# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в стихотворении?

Tags: пунктуация

Прикоснулась к нежности березовой,
Обняла душою будто Русь,
Написать стихами, а не прозою
О березках снова я берусь.

Белоствольные, кудрявые красавицы,
Я любуюсь ими без конца,
Жить среди березок мне так нравится,
Как родные эти деревца.

Встретила их в парке и растрогалась,
Стайками столпились тут и там,
Усмотрела них свою я молодость,
Радует в березках чистота.

Answer (score 1):

Я не увидел в расстановке знаков каких-либо ошибок. Стилистический момент: почти всегда в стихах в тех местах, где постановка знака препинания вариативна, авторы выбирают запятую — потому что так проще. На мой вкус, это несколько скучновато. Кроме того, отдельные знаки могут облегчить прочтение, поскольку будут более явно указывать на места, где следует делать паузы.

Прикоснулась к нежности березовой,
Обняла душою будто Русь (1)
Написать стихами, а не прозою
О березках снова я берусь.

Белоствольные (2) кудрявые красавицы,
Я любуюсь ими без конца (3)
Жить среди березок мне так нравится (4)
Как родные эти деревца.

Встретила их в парке и растрогалась (5)
Стайками столпились тут и там,
Усмотрела них свою я молодость,
Радует в березках чистота.

(1) Возможно тире, т.к. дальше идёт пояснение.
(2) Запятая не обязательна, прилагательные разного свойства. Но лучше оставить, чтобы это не отвлекало любителей искать пропущенные запятые.
(3) Можно и точку поставить, но, наверное, лучше запятую оставить. Я бы поставил точку с запятой, но многие почему-то избегают этот знак препинания.
(4) Аналогично (1).
(5) В письменной речи я бы поставил двоеточие. Но можно его заменить и на тире.

Ставить тире сразу во всех случаях, (1), (4) и (5) — это, пожалуй, перебор. Но кое-где можно для разнообразия.

Вообще, хорошее стихотворение. Душевное, легко читается и без избыточно простых рифм.